# Pressure on vertical rectangular plate submerged in water

Tags: fluid-statics

See task description in the image below:[image]

The solution manual solves the problem by calculating the hydrostatic force halfway down the car door,

i.e

[image]

Isn't this incorrect? My idea was to calculate the force by using pressure prisms/trapezoid, as demonstrated in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1f5PEJMz2g

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do that.  But since the area you are considering is a rectangle, will your answer differ?  Remember the pressure gradient is assumed to be linear.

Comment: Yeah, my answer differs quite a bit. Is the proposed solution actually the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Your formula gives the pressure, not the force. Pressure is force divided by surface.

Comment: Inside the car there still the air pressure of 1 bar. It should subtracted, but cancels the athmispheric pressure on the water surface.

Comment: Thank you, I should have mentioned that. After looking at the solution manual I believe that the author has just mixed up the definition of Pressure. By multiplying and not dividing the area on the hydrostatic force halfway down the car door I get the same answer as mine. I get 122kN by the way. I assume that is the correct answer? :-)